# Create a new file from another file in C

Tags: c, file, fopen, scanf, printf

I have a file with this format:

```
0.4
0.3
0.2
0.4
```

I need to create a new file with this format:

```
1 2

0.4 1 0
0.5 1 0 
0.3 0 1 
...
```

I wrote this function

```
void  adapta_fichero_serie(char file_input[50],char file_output[50], int np)
{

    FILE* val_f=fopen(file_input,"r");
    FILE* out_f=fopen(file_output,"w+");
    float temp[np+1];
    float tempo;
    int i=0;
    int uno=1;
    int flag=0;
    int due=2;
    int zero=0;
    int file_size;

    fprintf(out_f,"%d %d\n", np, due );

    while(!feof(val_f))
    {
        if(flag==0)
        {
            for(i=0;i<np;i++)
            {
                fscanf(val_f,"%f" ,&tempo);
                temp[i]=tempo;
                flag=1;
            }
        }

        fscanf(val_f,"%f",&tempo);
        temp[np]=tempo;

        for(i=0;i<np;i++)
        {
            fprintf(out_f,"%f\t",temp[i]);
        }

        if(temp[np-1]<=temp[np]) 
        fprintf(out_f,"%d\t%d ", uno, zero);
        else fprintf(out_f,"%d\t%d\n", zero, uno);  

        for(i=0;i<np;i++)
        {   
            tempo=temp[i+1];
            temp[i]=tempo;
        }
    }

    close(out_f);
    close(val_f);

}
```

and create new file with correct format but when i try to read this new file, the reading stopping at line 315 but the file is of 401 line. 
Can you help me? I hope my question is easy to understand!

Comment: That doesn't even compile. `close` takes an `int`, not a `FILE*`. And don't use `feof()`, because it's never correct.

Comment: This could be a feof() problem.  I've seen someone talking about that lately and wondered.  Beyond that, perhaps your output file has a end of file character within it throwing you off - since you are reading in text mode, I could see that happening.  BTW, compile with all warnings enabled and fix them to start.  There is a good chance that fixing your warnings will lead you to your bug!

Comment: thank you! I don't see that i use close! i think using fclose. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Just to record your solution from the comments, use `fclose` instead of `close` and make sure to pay attention to your compiler warnings as they would have pointed this out.

Comment: And if @KerrekSB wants the credit, he can definately have it as his was the comment that actaully called out the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your algorithm should do. Here is my view of it :)

```
void adapta_fichero_serie(const char *file_input, const char *file_output)
{
    float n_prev, n_cur; // Processed values as we read them
    FILE *in, *out; // Input-output files

    n_prev = 0; // Initial value for the first element to compare with

    in = fopen(file_input, "rt"); // open read only in text mode
    out = fopen(file_output, "wt+"); // append in text mode

    fprintf(out, "1\t2\n\n"); // write header: 1 <TAB> 2 <CR><CR>

    while (fscanf(in, "%f", &n_cur) == 1)  // run loop as long as we can read
    {
        fprintf(out, n_cur > n_prev ? "1\t0\n" : "0\t1"); // print depending on comparison
        n_prev = n_cur; // save value for the next iteration
    }

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
}
```